# simpledateformat format new Date() and then parse again return a different date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDD");
            logger.info("new Date()="+new Date());
            Date today = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date()));
            logger.info("today:"+today + ", today.getTime():" + today.getTime());
```

result:

> new Date()=Fri Sep 30 09:45:07 HKT 2022

> today:Sun Dec 26 00:00:00 HKT 2021, today.getTime():1640448000000

as above, why format and then parse the same date, will return a different date?

Comment: `"YYYYMMDD"` does not do what you think it does. Print the output of `sdf.format(new Date())` to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formatting pattern is wrong. The code letters are case-sensitive. So fix your use of uppercase and lowercase.

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

To capture the current date, use `LocalDate`. Specify the desired time zone as the **date varies around the globe** by time zone. Note that `LocalDate` does *not* contain a time zone. The zone is used only to determine the current date.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, year, month, and day, separated by a hyphen.

```
String s = today.toString() ;
```

Parse.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( s ) ;
```

Search Stack Overflow to learn more. All of this has been covered many times before.

Comment: If the OP wants the format YYYYMMDD, they can use `today.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)` and parse back using `LocalDate.parse(today.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE), DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)`.